# Mixing PHP and html.

Tags: php, html-table

I have the following PHP code:

```
$temp_str .= '

            <table width="300" height="84" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="80" rowspan="4"><img src="img/planets/1sm.jpg" width="80" height="82" /></td>
        <td width="110">System '.$user[location].'</td>
        <td width="110">'.$planets[planet_name].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">This planet is guarded by '.$planets[fighters].' Fighters</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Clan ID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attack</td>
        <td>Special Weapon</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

            ';
```

Simple enough and displays beautifully.

I'm trying to insert the following in the `Attack` and `Special weapon` box;

Attack;

```
if(($planets['login_id'] == $user['login_id']) ||
               ($planets['clan_id'] == $user['clan_id'] &&
               $planets['clan_id'] != 0) || ($user['login_id'] == ADMIN_ID) ||
               ($planets['fighters'] == 0) || $user['ship_id'] == NULL) {
                $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]><img src=\"img/icons/Land.png\" alt=\"Land\" /></a>";
            } else {
                if($flag_planet_attack != 0){
                    $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]&attack_planet=1><img src=\"img/icons/Attack.png\" alt=\"Attack\" /></a>";
```

Special Weapon;

```
if(ereg("sv",$user_ship['config'])) { //quark disrupter
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?quark=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Quark Displacer</a>";
                    } elseif(ereg("sw",$user_ship['config']) && $enable_superweapons == 1) { //terra maelstrom
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?terra=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Terra Maelstrom</a>";
                    }
                    if($planets['pass'] != '0') {
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]>Have Pass</a>";
```

But I keep on getting errors unexpected t_string, > everything.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Your help is much appreciated.

Below is the full code that I'm trying to ... split, I guess:

```
if(($planets['login_id'] == $user['login_id']) ||
               ($planets['clan_id'] == $user['clan_id'] &&
               $planets['clan_id'] != 0) || ($user['login_id'] == ADMIN_ID) ||
               ($planets['fighters'] == 0) || $user['ship_id'] == NULL) {
                $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]><img src=\"img/icons/Land.png\" alt=\"Land\" /></a>";
            } else {
                if($flag_planet_attack != 0){
                    $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]&attack_planet=1><img src=\"img/icons/Attack.png\" alt=\"Attack\" /></a>";
                    if(ereg("sv",$user_ship['config'])) { //quark disrupter
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?quark=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Quark Displacer</a>";
                    } elseif(ereg("sw",$user_ship['config']) && $enable_superweapons == 1) { //terra maelstrom
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?terra=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Terra Maelstrom</a>";
                    }
                    if($planets['pass'] != '0') {
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]>Have Pass</a>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $planets = dbr(1);
    }//end while
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but it seems that I'm leaving something open.

```
$temp_str .= '

            <table width="300" height="84" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="80" rowspan="4"><img src="img/planets/1sm.jpg" width="80" height="82" /></td>
        <td width="110">System '.$user[location].'</td>
        <td width="110">'.$planets[planet_name].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">This planet is guarded by '.$planets[fighters].' Fighters</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Clan ID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>';
        if(($planets['login_id'] == $user['login_id']) ||
               ($planets['clan_id'] == $user['clan_id'] &&
               $planets['clan_id'] != 0) || ($user['login_id'] == ADMIN_ID) ||
               ($planets['fighters'] == 0) || $user['ship_id'] == NULL) {
                $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]><img src=\"img/icons/Land.png\" alt=\"Land\" /></a>";
            } else {
                if($flag_planet_attack != 0){
                    $temp_str .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]&attack_planet=1><img src=\"img/icons/Attack.png\" alt=\"Attack\" /></a></td>
        <td>";
            if(ereg("sv",$user_ship['config'])) { //quark disrupter
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?quark=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Quark Displacer</a>";
                    } elseif(ereg("sw",$user_ship['config']) && $enable_superweapons == 1) { //terra maelstrom
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?terra=1&planet_num=$planets[planet_id]>Fire Terra Maelstrom</a>";
                    }
                    if($planets['pass'] != '0') {
                        $temp_str .= " - <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]>Have Pass</a>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $planets = dbr(1);
    }//end while
}       
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

            ';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mention an array value in a string you need to enclose it inside { and }. Example:

```
$temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?quark=1&planet_num={$planets['planet_id']}>Fire Quark Displacer</a>";
```

or

```
$temp_str .= " - <a href=attack.php?quark=1&planet_num=" . $planets['planet_id'] . ">Fire Quark Displacer</a>";
```

Comment: on no, Johny, the code by itself displays ok, i just need to split it in the boxes.

Comment: That should fix the T_STRING errors, though, which was your question. To get it inside a string, you could put the top set of code after the code which determines what you want to link to where - and in the part where to decide what you want linked to where define some variables, which you make reference to in the full block afterwards - if that makes sense. Or split the first part up surrounding your if() bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your hrefs for your `<a>` tags you have `"planet.php?planet_id=$planets[planet_id]>Have Pass</a>"`, is `planet_id` a variable or a key? Since it's double quoted you could do something like `"planet.php?planet_id={$planets['planet_id']}>Have Pass</a>"`

Answer (score 0):

No sure how you are 'putting' this in 'a box', but if you want a string to contain the quotes it is encapsulated in, you should escape those quotes, like so:

```
$string = 'This is a text with quotes. Don\'t forget to escape';
```

It may be easier to use double quotes. Note that unlike single quoted strings, you can use variables in double quoted strings, so `$string = "--- $a ---"` will fill in the value of `$a` in the string.

```
$string = "Single 'quotes' can be used in double-quote-embedded strings";
```

If you need to embed large chunks of HTML or JavaScript in your PHP code, you might want to use this:

```
$string = <<<AnyIdentifier

Any text containing special characters. Note that variables are parsed in 
these strings too.

AnyIdentifier;
// Note, closing identifier must occur at the start of the line.
```

[edit]

```
// Code to create weapon HTML goes here. Rename $temp_str to $weaponCode
....
if($flag_planet_attack != 0){
  $weaponCode .= "- <a href=planet.php?planet_id=$planets[plane
.....

// Code to create attack HTML goes here. Rename $temp_str to $attackCode
$attackCode = '... Generated Attack HTML';

$temp_str = <<<totalHtml
<table>
<!-- Note how you can use variables inside this kind of string declaration. -->
<tr>$weaponCode</tr><tr>$attackCode</tr>
</table>

totalHtml;
// String declaration ends on the line above. Note that that line must not 
// contain leading not trailing spaces.
```

Comment: im trying to place that information in separate boxes in a table. thats what i mean by it bro.

Comment: Ah, I see your edit now. You cannot put code inside a string. You build a variable (`temp_var`) in code, which you can later use to build a string like this: `$html = '<table>.....' . $temp_str1 . '</tr><tr>' . $temp_str2 . '</table>';` As you can see, you need to use two separate names for the 'attack' and 'weapon' variables.

Comment: temp_str is an identifier though. i need to display the code inside that. it identifies the whole table.

Comment: oh i see what you mean. ill try that in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`... $planets[planet_id] ...` doesn't work.

it has to be `... {$planets['planet_id']} ...`

Comment: The code that im trying to display displays ok by itself, i'm tring to place these in a table.